# NodeJS nedb function not awaiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, nedb

Function `checkExists` is taking too long to execute. Tried to use await async function but had no effect. `var exists = await checkExists(data.email);` is returning undefined because not awaiting for `checkExists`.

I have my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('./private/signUpAPI')(app);

app.listen(80, () => console.log('listening on 80'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));
```

And my signUpAPI.js:

```
const DataStore = require('nedb');
const express = require('express');

const database = new DataStore('private/database.db');
database.loadDatabase();

module.exports = function api(app){
    app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));
    app.post('/signUpAPI', async (request, response) => {
        console.log("Sign Up Request received!");
        const data = request.body;

        var exists = await checkExists(data.email);

        console.log(exists)
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Added to DB");
        console.log('-------------------------' + '\n');
        database.insert(data);
        const testData = {"status": "success"};
        response.send(testData);
    });    
}

async function checkExists(email){
    var exists = false;

    database.find({"email": email}, async function(err, docs){
        if (docs.length > 0){exists = true;}
        console.log(docs.length);
        return exists;
    });
}
```

this is the node output when running index.js and calling the `fetch('/signUpAPI')`:

```
Sign Up Request received!
undefined
{
  email: 'a',
  username: 'a',
  hashPass: 'da180265625ebeaf62f4ee1813bdc28faeaf79f0b2b329290758a1c095111ae8',
  salt: 'g8VkTBV$+Bh35K9ns7Zt*9^CH#M=VELSzKUX=H3^+5kpFV=bEbVfXFtF*GGYHOa#'
}
Added to DB
-------------------------

37
```

I currently have 37 entries in the DB with the same data hence the `console.log(docs.length)` returning 37.

But this is executing last and appears at the bottom of the console when it should appear at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb-promise

so you can use await for database queries and you can change your code like this -

```
async function checkExists(email) {
    const record = await database.findOne({ email });
    console.log(record);
    if (record) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions you want to wait should return a promise in order to wait for response.
You either resolve the promise if the operation result is success or reject with an error.

The flow should like something like this;

```
async function func1()
{
    try
    {
        var tmp = await func2();
        console.log(tmp);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    } 
}

async funcion func2()
{
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject)
    {
        if(true)
        {
            resolve("success");
        }
        else
        {
            reject("error");
        }
    });
}
```